# Disable Gnome on boot in Antergos

Tags: arch-linux, gnome

I use Antegos (a distribution based on Arch Linux) and I installed GNOME in my system.

- How can I disable GNOME running at system boot?
- After booting without GNOME, how can I start it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you mean by GNOME auto starting is, most likely, actually `gdm` (GNOME Display Manager) which provides the login screen. Just disable the service to stop it from autostarting. Arch uses `systemd`, so you want to do:

```
# systemctl disable gdm
```

Reboot and `gdm` won't automatically start. You can then manually start it whenever you want with:

```
# systemctl start gdm
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable completely the graphical session and boot into rescue mode edit the kernel line in grub at startup and add an `s` at the end of it. Alternatively you can also add `systemd.unit=rescue` to that line. See [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154354)

To start gnome from commandline it depends on the login manager. If you have gdm for example try `sudo gdm`.

If it's just that you installed gnome and want to switch to a previous desktop manager, look for a menu named "sessions" or something like it at the login screen.